# Why are my bar matplotlib chart labels of pandas data off by 1?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to create a bar chart to compare the values in two pandas series. It's working but the labels are off by one, with the first one being omitted and therefore the last bar group having no label. Here's my code:

```
def save_compare_dissatisfaction(series1, series2):
    df = pd.concat([series1, series2], axis=1)
    df.columns = ['group1', 'group2']
    labels = df.index.to_list()
    genz_data = df['group1'].values
    elders_data = df['group2'].values
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    index = np.arange(len(df))
    width = 0.35
    rects1 = ax.bar(index - width/2, genz_data, width, label='Group 1')
    rects2 = ax.bar(index + width/2, elders_data, width, label='Group 2')
    ax.set_ylabel('Dissatisfaction Rate')
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.savefig('charts/bar.png')
```

Here's the output:

[image: bar.png]

Note that if I `print(labels)` any place after they're defined, I get a list with six values:

```
['Status Level', 'Fulfilling Job', 'Work Praised', 'Undervalued', 'Recent Raise', 'Pleased with Perks']
```

Most of the code used here was taken from [matplotlib's "Grouped bar chart with labels"](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py) example.

Comment: Never use `set_xticklabels` without also setting the positions (e.g. via `set_xticks`

Comment: That was it, ty. Care to put it in an answer so I can give you the credit? :)